# Number of blanks in a column based on a distinct value in another column

Tags: powerbi

I currently have the Power BI that gives me the value of the first step in my request. Now I would like to reduce this value further by adding a condition to the COUNTROWS, which would consider distinct values (Activity Code) in another column. For example, there is a project code column (e.g., 11111, 11112, 11113, etc.). Each project code has various activities with different codes, start and end dates. Open activities have no end date. The current measure I have (listed below) gives me total number of blanks in the Close Date column. I need help adding to the code so blanks are counted only for distinct Activity Codes so the output is total open Activities.

What I currently have (Total empty rows):

```
Year Open = CALCULATE (
            COUNTROWS ( Activities ),
            KEEPFILTERS ( ISBLANK ( Activities[Close_Date] ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CALCULATE(
  DISTINCTCOUNT('Activities'[Code]),
  KEEPFILTERS ( ISBLANK ( Activities[Close_Date] ) )
)
```